# java.lang.String cannot be cast to Bean.Course_Bean

Tags: java, android, spring

I want to get school_id from Course_Bean.java. i have tried but the error is :

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to Bean.Course_Bean

this is AllTopic_Fragment.java

```
 public AllTopic_Fragment(Context mContext, Object obj) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    mNavigationDeleget = (NavigationDeleget) mContext;
    this.object = ((Course_Bean)obj).getId(); //in this line was error
    this.object2 = ((Course_Bean)obj).getSchool_id();
    Bitmap default_bitmap = Util.drawableToBitmap(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.profile_default));
```

This is TopicMainFragment.java

```
public Topic_MainFragment(Context mContext, Object object) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        mNavigationDeleget = (NavigationDeleget) mContext;
        this.obj = object;
    }     

private void displayView(String fragmentName, Object obj) {
        //deatachFragment(fragTransaction);
        // mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        if (fragmentName.equals(VerlinConstant.ALLTOPIC_FRAGMENT)) {
            mFragment = new AllTopic_Fragment(mContext, obj); //this line was error
        } else if (fragmentName.equals(VerlinConstant.RECOMMENDED_FRAGMENT)) {
            mFragment = new Recommended_Fragment(mContext, obj);
```

and in this script too, TopicMainFragment.java

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mFragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.topic_main_fragment, container, false);
        intializeGUI(view);

        if (VerlinConstant.SELECT_FRAG.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            displayView(VerlinConstant.ALLTOPIC_FRAGMENT, obj); //this line was error
            changeViewColor(alltopic_tab_txt);
        } else if (VerlinConstant.SELECT_FRAG.equalsIgnoreCase("all")) {
            displayView(VerlinConstant.ALLTOPIC_FRAGMENT, obj);
            changeViewColor(alltopic_tab_txt);
```

please help

Comment: What is Course_Bean? Exception seems pretty obvious to me

Comment: `displayView(VerlinConstant.ALLTOPIC_FRAGMENT, obj);` -> where do you initialize `obj`?

Comment: course_bean is file that saved/returned school_id value, so i want to get school_id value from course_bean.java @Denny

Comment: i have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Error means that at line

```
this.object = ((Course_Bean)obj).getId(); //in this line was error
```

obj.getId() method returns a `String` object, while you are casting a `Course_Bean` type to it. You should use a simple String without any casts to retrieve id value:

```
String id = obj.getId();
```

However, you should call `getId()` method not on `Object`, but on your `Course_Bean` instances (assuming you've declared such method there) since `Object` doesn't have such method. You need to refactor whole code since it's heavily lied on `Object`s - this is not how the OOP is supposed to be used.
Also, I suggest using `long` or `int` for id field since it's a number.

Comment: I doubt this will even compile, since `Object` does not have a `getId()` method..., not a viable solution

Comment: Mm, of course it won't, didn't notice that, thanks! Updated my answer